# openpyxl throwing error on load_workbook

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

My program is as simple as

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\filepath')
```

However when I run I receive a

'IndexError was unhandled by user code
Message: list index out of range
'

error. I can't seem to find any solutions to this online. My version of openpyxl is 2.4.8. If it helps I'm working on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error you're getting along with the version of openpyxl you have installed.

Comment: @CharlieClark done.

Comment: That is not the full traceback.

Comment: That's all I get

Comment: Try it in a terminal. If that's all you get than we cannot help you.

Comment: So I tried the issue at home using a different IDE and my code worked just fine with slight modification that wasn't relevant... I'll try to fix it again and hopefully find out what caused it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path with extension. Like this

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='C:\Users\filepath\book.xlsx')
```

filename needs to be a path or a file-like object.

Comment: Right, I currently have 
`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'C:\Users\name\Documents\book.xlsx')` 
but I am still getting the same error